# Spring3 @autowire Explain?

Tags: java, spring

I have been going through the tutorials of Spring 3 at 
http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-annotation-controller-1.html

But i have one doubt regarding autowired feature of spring3.

If you look at sample code given at the site, it has used `@Autowired` before `setUserService` method.
Now i have several question about it.

1. Is this the standard of using autowire ?? that is create a interface, implement its method and then finally in your controller class use the interface class's setter method.
2. if i use autowire in that way what is the benefit i got ?
3. what is the substitute code of using autowire ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .1. Is this the standard of using autowire ?? that is create a interface, implement its method and then finally in your controller class use the interface class's setter method.

Yes, this is more-or-less standard way, but this is just a convention. [Some](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/in_the_age_of_dryness) consider this to be a bad practice. It is not enforced in any way by Spring (however you might be forced to add CGLIB to your dependencies if you don't use interfaces).

> .2. if i use autowire in that way what is the benefit i got ?

Don't know what do you mean by *that way*, but just to name few benefits: easier testing, decoupling, less infrastructure code...

> .3. what is the substitute code of using autowire ?

Again, hard to tell what do you mean by *substitute code*. There are plenty of other techniques: you can use XML, `@Configuration`, `@Resource`, `@Inject`, (probably few other *ats*), constructor injection, field injection, setter injection (the one in the tutorial), looking up Spring beans directly from `BeanFactory`...

Comment: Thanks for replying

2. if i use autowire in that way what is the benefit i got ?
I meant referring to the example given in link, 'that way' means create a interface, implement it and use a setter method..

3. what is the substitute code of using autowire ?
I meant, without spring how would i had implemented the above code..

A new Question: The mentioned example has used autowire and you have mentioned other annotations like @config. which is the best method of all ? is autowire the best way to implement ?

Comment: @vipul12389: Ad. 2: many people use interface to separate contract from implementation and make it easier to switch implementations in the future. However others find the extra interface to be just a noise (see link above). Ad. 3. Well, without Spring... you would have to do this manually :-). Ad. new question: presently I prefer mixture of `@Autowired` and `@Configuration`. It is really up to you, Spring gives you this freedom.

Comment: ok thanks, you have answered to almost to my query. but still a small Question remains is that you said that i need to do it manually, so can you post the code that how manually autowwire works ?

Comment: @vipul12389: that's the whole point of Spring/Guice/CDI - you don't have to do anything. Without Spring DI you would have to create all the objects yourself in correct order and inject them. A lot of work that the DI container handles for you.

Comment: Since this discussion is getting a bit too long please post another question describing your issues. Don't forget to post a follow-up link here so I can find it.

Comment: Tomasz, Here is the reference link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532948/spring3-autowire-alternative-code